# How to add an event listener to some HTML element from Rust which calls a trivial JS function?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, web-sys

I have the "`on_event`" JS function:

```
function on_event(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

And I have the "`button`" HTML element builder in Rust:

```
let window = web_sys::window().expect("no `window` object");
let document = window.document().expect("no `document` object");
let body = document.body().expect("no `body` object");

let button = document.create_element("button")?;
// ...
body.append_child(&button);
```

How to link the "`on_event`" JS function with the "`button`" HTML element from the Rust code?

At the end I need something like:

```
button.add_event_listener("click", "on_event"); // <- What I need to use here instead of this code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a trivial JS function I can use HTML attributes:

```
button.set_attribute("onclick", "on_event('on_event callback fired!')")?;
```

Also it can be used for Rust functions exported to JS with `#[wasm_bindgen]` and imported to the global namespace.

In Rust:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn on_event(message: &str) {
  console_log(message);
}

// ...

button.set_attribute("onclick", "wasm.on_event('on_event callback fired!')")?;
```

In JS:

```
<script type="module">
  import init from './pkg/wasm_project.js';
  window.wasm = await init('./pkg/wasm_project_bg.wasm');
</script>
```

If you are using [Trunk](https://trunkrs.dev/) then instead of edit of JS file you can create `Trunk.toml` file in the root of the project folder and put this code:

```
[build]
pattern_script = "<script type=\"module\">import init, * as wasm from '{base}{js}';init('{base}{wasm}').then(()=>window.wasm=wasm);</script>"
```